# Using GNOME-Settings-Daemon in XFCE

Tags: gnome, xfce, gnome-settings-daemon

I haven't seen this anywhere else, and this is the only major showstopping issue that I have with a transition to XFCE.

System:  HP Pavillion DM1-3200US

---

I'm interested in moving over to XFCE, but my main issue is that media keys don't work properly.  I've tried the solution provided on XFCE's Wiki (mapping the keys), but that isn't a proper solution for me - the laptop I'm on doesn't light up when the sound is muted with that solution.

I've seen that `gnome-settings-daemon` actually properly detects the media keys on my netbook, but when I experimented with that in a live environment, it only worked for a single session, and failed to work.

My question then becomes:

1. Is it a good idea to use `gnome-settings-daemon` on my XFCE build?  If so, what would I need to install/include/build/divine/hack to ensure that it worked consistently throughout a normal days' use?
2. If `gnome-settings-daemon` is not a tenable long-term solution, what would I need to perform to not only get media keys to work properly, but also to get my netbook's "Mute" light to work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've taken a stab at this with the Live CD environment, and I'm confident that it will translate properly over on the full installation.

---

I went ahead and installed `gnome-settings-daemon` and added it to the start-up list of programs.  After disabling the XFCE Volume Daemon (or `xfce4-volumed`) from the start-up list, and updated `xfce4-power-manager`, I'm able to report that my media keys are working as expected in my Xubuntu session.

Now, I have to figure out how to get them to work when on the login page.  But I won't despise a small beginning here.

Comment: Updates to your question go in your *question*, not in here.

Comment: Wasn't an update to my question; I believe that this *is* an answer to the question.  I have to wait 48 hours to accept it, though.